# Multiple Linear Regression in R getting coef. for both levels

Tags: r, linear-regression

In multiple linear regression getting coefficients of both levels of a factor of two levels.

```
> levels(pmsm_temperature_data$stator_yoke)
[1] ""         "Negative" "Positive"
> lm_b <- lm(pm ~ ambient+coolant+u_d+u_q+motor_speed+ torque+stator_yoke + stator_winding, data= pmsm_temperature_data)
> coef(lm_b)
        (Intercept)             ambient             coolant                 u_d                 u_q         motor_speed 
        -0.25527171          0.28312684         -0.05159457         -0.25151648         -0.06007881          0.11421214 
             torque stator_yokeNegative stator_yokePositive      stator_winding 
        -0.26052010          0.13612099          0.37956846          0.53693677
```

is it correct???

Comment: This is because 1) it is using the empty level as the base level. There is an empty level. You definitely have to code that as missing, ie NA eg `pmsm_temperature_data$stator_yoke[pmsm_temperature_data$stator_yoke==""] <- NA` 2) You are using a different contrast eg sum instead of treatment. If this is the case, restart your R to go back to the default, or use the `options` function to change back to the default.

Comment: yeah there was an empty level. thanks